# upload image from flutter to node js server

Tags: node.js, flutter

I tried to upload an image from flutter app to node js server but give undefined response from server.
flutter code:

File ?file;

```
 Future pickImage()async{
    try{
    final file=await ImagePicker().pickImage(source:ImageSource.camera);
    if(file==null){
      print("no image selected");
    }
    else{
      final tempPath=File(file.path);
      setState(() {
        this.file=tempPath;
      }); 
      print(file);
    }
    }
    on PlatformException catch(e){
      print("failed to pick image $e");
    }
  }
 
    Future upload()async{
      Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:8000/image");
      http.MultipartRequest request = http.MultipartRequest("POST",uri);
      request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('files',file!.path));
      http.StreamedResponse response=await request.send();
      var reponseBytes=await response.stream.toBytes();
      var responseString=utf8.decode(reponseBytes);
      print(responseString);
    }
```

server

```
router.post("/image",(req,res)=>{
  res.send(req.files)
  console.log(req.files)
})
```

What I have done wrong.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use multer library to get file in node.js app, this is a simple example for multer :

```
    let multer = require('multer'),
    multerImage = multer().single('image');

    exports.uploadAvatar = (req, res) => {


getTokenPayLoad(data => {

    let phone = data.phoneNumber;


    multerImage(req, res, () => {


        let file = req.file;

        if (isUndefined(file))
            return Json.builder(Response.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

        let {
            fileUrl
        } = File.validationAndWriteFile(file.buffer, Util.getFileFormat(file.originalname));

        Update.img(phone, fileUrl, result => {
            if (!result)
                return Json.builder(Response.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

            Json.builder(Response.HTTP_OK);
        });

    });

});

 }
```

Comment: I am getting nothing in console

Comment: this answer can help you https://thewebdev.info/2021/07/04/how-to-fix-the-req-files-undefined-error-with-express/   but  I suggestion to use multer

Comment: I am getting undefined on console.log(req.files)